# Add single quotation mark

Tags: vb.net

I create a query using this code

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To myMetaColumnInformation.result.Count - 1
        query.Append("[")
        query.Append(myMetaColumnInformation.result(i).questionCode.ToString)

        query.Append("] ")
        query.Append(typeList(i))
        query.Append("""")

        query.Append(", ")
    Next
```

My problem is that `query.Append("""")` creates two quotation marks but I just need one. If I reduce the command to `query.Append(""")` the code does not run through. Every hint I can get is about adding two quotation marks but not for one. I also tried \" but this does not help as well. Anyone who can help me get this done?

Comment: Don't create sql qeuries including the parameters with string concatenation. Use parameterized queries

Comment: That is a good hint. Thanks.

Comment: With regards to the question as asked, `query.Append("""")` does not create two quotation marks. What it does is append one double-quote. Because double-quotes are `String` delimiters in VB, the language and the IDE represent one double-quote by escaping it with a second.  It's much like C# escapes a backslash with another backslash. The `String` itself only contains one double-quote, although the IDE will show two because it's escaped.

Comment: The thing is, why are you using double-quotes in the first place?  SQL uses single-quotes to delimit strings so you should have been appending a single-quote in the first place, which doesn't need escaping.

Comment: As suggested though, you should not be doing either but rather using parameters. I would suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html). You can still build the SQL dynamically and use parameters, like [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298).